# how to prove the general distributive law

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been self-studying the book on set theory by Donald Monk ("Intro to Set Theory"). I'm getting stuck in the proof of this part of the general distributive law (p.54):

$\bigcup_{i\in I}\bigcap_{j\in J}\boldsymbol{A}_{ij}\supseteq\bigcap_{\boldsymbol{F}\in\,{}^{I}J}\bigcup_{i\in I}\boldsymbol{A}_{i,\boldsymbol{F}i}$

where $\boldsymbol{A}$ is an indexed family of sets with domain $I\times J$, where $I$ and $J$ are sets.

Proof:

Let $x\in\bigcap_{\boldsymbol{F}\in\,{}^{I}J}\bigcup_{i\in I}\boldsymbol{A}_{i,\boldsymbol{F}i}$.

Then $x\in\bigcup_{i\in I}\boldsymbol{A}_{i,\boldsymbol{F}i}$, $\forall\boldsymbol{F}\in{}^{I}J$.

Thus, for each $\boldsymbol{F}\in{}^{I}J$, $\exists i\in I$ s.t. $x\in\boldsymbol{A}_{i,\boldsymbol{F}i}$.

To complete the proof, I need to show that, for some $i_{0}\in I$, $x\in\boldsymbol{A}_{ij}$, for all $j\in J$. I know that, for each $j\in J$, we can easily define a function $\boldsymbol{F}\in{}^{I}J$ s.t. $j=\boldsymbol{F}i$, for some $i\in I$: e.g., let $\boldsymbol{F}=I\times\left\{ j\right\}$.  Thus $x\in\boldsymbol{A}_{ij}$ for every $j\in J$ and some $i\in I$ (that corresponds to this $j$).

I have no idea how to proceed, or if I'm on the right track at all. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's prove the contrapositive. If $x\notin \bigcup_{i\in I}\bigcap_{j\in J} A_{ij}$ then for every $i$ there exists some $j_i$ such that $x\notin A_{ij_i}$. Define $F$ by $F(i)=j_i$ for each $i\in I$. Then $x\notin \bigcup_{i\in I} A_{iF(i)}$.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. That was too easy. I need to contemplate this